# Concatenate rows based on user selection

Tags: powerbi, concatenation

I have a table like this:

| Ticket Number | Client | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T123 | Andy | Question |
| T456 | Bob | Issue |
| T789 | Charlie | Problem |

I use the filters to display which tickets I am interested in, then open Excel and use

```
= "www.myticket.url/" & TEXTJOIN("&",TRUE,A:A)
```

in order to open the url to display all my tickets (in this case, `www.myticket.url/T123&T456&T789`)

Is there a way to display this dynamically created URL directly in Power BI rather than having to download to Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a measure using [CONCATENATEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/concatenatex-function-dax) DAX function to concatenate the values in `Ticket Number` column, with `&` separator.

The measure could look like this (where `Table` is the name of the table):

```
URL = "http://www.myticket.url/" & CONCATENATEX('Table', [Ticket Number], "&")
```

Probably you will also want to [set the data category](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-hyperlinks-in-tables?tabs=powerbi-desktop#format-a-url-as-a-hyperlink-in-power-bi-desktop) of the measure to Web URL.

[image: "www.myticket.url/"]